# Law of total expectation

Tags: probability

A man is trapped in a mine containing three doors. The first door leads to a tunnel that will take
him to safety after walking for 3 hours. The second door leads to a tunnel that will return him to
the mine after walking for 5 hours. The third door leads to a tunnel that will return him to the
mine after walking for 7 hours.
Assuming the man is equally likely to choose each door, what is the expected length of time until
the man reaches safety?

I know I need to use the law of total expectation, but I have no idea how to construct the model, anyone could help me? Thanks

Comment: This is an absorbing Markov chain.

Comment: I didn't learn Markov chain

Comment: See my answer for an easy solution not involving Markov chains.

Answer (score 2):

Fifteen hours.

One way to do this:

Let $T$ be the expected amount of time it takes to exit. Then by the assumptions:
$$T = 3(1/3)+ (5+T)(1/3) + (7 + T)(1/3)$$
Where the factors of one-third are there due to the probabilities for each possible outcome.

Solve for $T$.

Comment: Perfect and elegant !

Comment: @Sudarsan Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the expected number of hours to reach safety. If he takes the first door, he’ll reach safety in $3$ hours. If he takes the second door, he’ll be back at the beginning after $5$ hours, and he can then expect to take another $T$ hours, so in this case he can expect to reach safety in $T+5$ hours. Similarly, if he takes the third door, he can expect to reach safety in $T+7$ hours. Each of these cases occurs with probability $\frac13$. Can you apply the law of total expectation now?

**Note:** I’m assuming that he makes a random choice each time, unlikely as that seems in the real world!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following experiment. With probability $\frac{1}{3}$ each you are generating $3$ numbers $3, 5, 7$ at random. The first time you generate a $3$ you stop the experiment. What is the expected sum of the numbers that you generated?

EDIT: In case you wanted a direct approach to get the same answer of $15$ hours as given in other (elegant) approaches via recursions, you can apply the law of total expectation directly as follows.

The man can get out in any of $N=1,2,\dots$ steps and all of these events are disjoint and they partition the sample space.

$$\mathbb{E}[\text{Time to get out}] = \sum_{N=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[\text{time spent wastedly in N-1 steps} \mid \text{N steps and he's out}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{out in N steps}]$$

The above can be computed (which I'll leave for you to find out how to) and the expression that comes out is:
$$\sum_{N=1}^{\infty} \left[3+(N-1)6\right]\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{N-1}\frac{1}{3}$$

which can be simplified using the general AP-GP sum formula.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the time till the man is free.
Also, let $Y$ be a random variable denoting the door the man chooses the first time. Then $Y$ takes three distinct values, say $1$, $2$, or $3$, with equal probability.

If the man chooses the first door, i.e., if $Y=1$, then he is free immediately (or better after 3 hours exactly), and
$$
E[T | Y=1] = 3.
$$
If he chooses the second door, then he is back at the mine after $5$ hours. Now the "game" starts fresh, except 5 hours have passed. So,
$$
E[T | Y=2] = 5 + E[T].
$$
Similarly,
$$
E[T | Y=3] = 7 + E[T].
$$
Now, you should be able to use law of total expectation to compute $E[T]$:
$$
E[T] = E_{Y}\left[E[T|Y]\right] = \sum_{y=1}^{3} Pr(Y=y) \cdot E[T|Y=y].
$$